# JBoss 6: what's the difference between the directories common/lib and client?

Tags: jboss, client, apache-commons, jboss6.x

I found common libraries like Apache commons-lang.jar in `/client`, but not in `/common/lib`.
Q's:

What's the purpose of the `/client` directory and how is it different from `/common/lib`? (I copied my commons-lang.jar from `/client` to `/common/lib` to resolve CNFE issues.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/common/lib` is part of the server's classpath. `/client` is not part of the classpath, it's there to provide the JARs that any clients of the server may need to interact with it.

As to why commons-lang is in `/client` but not `/common/lib`, I don't know, but it's likely there to satisfy a dependency of something else in `/client`.

I recommend against changing the contents of `/common/lib`. The JARs in there are very specific, and are used by the server itself. If your application requires commons-lang, it should go in the WAR or EAR's private `lib` directory.

Comment: I had expected this. Neither do I know why common-lang is not in /common/lib. I'm wondering even more why the Seam libs are missing in /client, given that this is their primary framework. JBoss (6) even comes its own deployer. Thanks

Comment: @Kawu: Seam isn't part of JBossAS, it's bundled separately.